# A problem occurred configuring project ":app" > Cound not create task 'app:class.main()' > sourceset with name 'main' not found : using macbook M1

Tags: java, android-developer-api

I am new to android studio and using MacBook M1. just wrote my first java class but whenever I run the project it shows the following error. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQZPZ.png)

Comment: You need a main class as described.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.